# How does convergence in total variation of random variables compare to other modes of convergence?

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence

Suppose $X,Y$ are random variables. We define the total variation distance of random variables to be $$d_{TV}(X,Y)=\inf \lbrace\mathbb{P}(|X'-Y'|>0): \text{ $X', Y'$ are couplings of $X,Y$ respectively}\rbrace$$
What is the relationship between convergence in with respect to the metric $d_{TV}$ and the other modes of convergence. For example if $$d_{TV}(X_n,X)\rightarrow 0\quad n\rightarrow\infty$$  Then does $X_n\rightarrow X$ in probability, distribution, a.s., $L^p$, etc?

I am having trouble on how to work with $d_{TV}$, as I don't know much about couplings.

Answer (score 4):

First of all, note that the metric does only depend on the distributions of $X$ and $Y$, i.e.

$$d_{\text{TV}}(X,Y) = d_{\text{TV}}(X',Y') \tag{1}$$

holds for any $X \sim X'$ and $Y \sim Y'$. This means in particular that we cannot expect that convergence in the total variation distance implies pointwise convergence, $L^p$-convergence or convergence in probability as the following example shows.

**Example** Let $X$ be a random variable and $Y \sim X$, $Y \neq X$. Then $X_n := X$ converges in total variation distance to $Y$. On the other hand, $X_n = X$ does obviously in general *not* converge to $Y$ almost surely (in probability/$L^p$-sense, respectively).

One can show that convergence in total variation distance implies convergence in distribution. Moreover, there are a relations to a lot of other (probability) metrics; see e.g. *Gibbs, Su: On choosing and bounding probability metrics* for a survey.