# Convergence in Total Variation Implies Convergence in Distribution

Tags: probability, measure-theory

Suppose $X,Y$ are random variables. We define the total variation distance of random variables to be

$d(X,Y)= \inf \{P(|X′−Y′|>0): X′,Y′$ are couplings of $ X,Y$ respectively$\}$.

Does convergence in total variation imply convergence in distribution?

My feeling is that it should but I'm having trouble proving it.

Thanks!

Comment: The total variation distance involves a supremum not an infimum.

Comment: There are two ways of defining it for the random variable setting. This is the one given in the problem statement.

Comment: @Anonymous You are the author of this [question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1003616/), aren't you?

Comment: @saz, ironically I'm not! Although I did copy their definition. I'm new so it wouldn't let me comment/follow up on your answer to the question you linked.

Comment: @Anonymous I see. Quite the coincidence. Do you know that $X_n$ converges in distribution to $X$ iff $$\int f(X_n) \, d\mathbb{P} \to \int f(X) \, d\mathbb{P}$$ for all bounded, continuous $f$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us use the dual representation of the total variation distance:
$$
d_{TV}(X,Y) = \sup_{f: \mathcal X \to [-1,1]} Ef(X) - Ef(Y)
$$

Then for every positive (measurable) bounded $f$:
\begin{align}
Ef(X_n)&\le Ef(X) +  \sup_{\mathcal X} |f|\times d_{TV}(X_n,X)\\
Ef(X_n)&\ge Ef(X) -  \sup_{\mathcal X} |f|\times d_{TV}(X_n,X)
\end{align}

Comment: Why exactly does the first equality hold? I understand that I can write e.g. $P(A)$ as $E(\mathbb{1}_A X)$ for $X \sim P$. But then I only get $f\colon\mathcal{X} \to \{0,1\}$ or $f\colon\mathcal{X} \to \{-1,0,1\}$, respectively. Where does this $[-1,1]$ set come from?